# clang vs gcc: different code for volatile access

Tags: c++, gcc, assembly, clang, volatile

Consider this example:

```
volatile unsigned int x;
unsigned int y;

void f() {
    x /= 2;
}
void g() {
    y /= 2;
}
```

When compiled with -Os, clang-6.0 produces on x64 for both f and g the same `shrl <offset>(%rip)` instruction pattern (See https://godbolt.org/g/hUPprL), while gcc-7.3 produces this (See https://godbolt.org/g/vMcKVV) for f():

```
 mov 0x200b67(%rip),%eax # 601034 <x>
 shr %eax
 mov %eax,0x200b5f(%rip) # 601034 <x>
```

Is this just a missed optimization or is there a justification for gcc to reject `shrl <offset>(%rip)` in case of volatile access? Who is wrong?

Comment: If they both work correctly, neither is wrong, they're just different.

Comment: @PasserBy:I think the OP knows that, he's asking if this is a missed optimization.

Comment: Thanks Michael. If both produce the same behaviour, then gcc exposes a "missed optimization bug", because it clearly knows how to size-optimize 'y/=2'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just a missed optimization by gcc. Both implementations preserve the read from and write to `x` precisely, and thus are correct.

"Under the hood" operating on a memory operand performs the same loads and stores as the longer implementation.

Comment: Yes, gcc doesn't like to fold `volatile` loads/stores into other operations.  In this case it's also a missed performance optimization, according to [Agner Fog's testing](http://agner.org/optimize): Sandybridge-family runs `shr [mem], imm` as 3 fused-domain uops, the same as separate load/shr/store, and more compact code is usually better for L1i cache density and uop-cache density.  (Agner's tables for Haswell/Skylake appear to be wrong; it's still only 1 ALU uop for port0 or 6 for memory-destination shifts.  He says `2p06 p237 p4`, but I tested on SKL and it's really `p06 p23 p237 p4` )